# Getting Elements positioned correctly

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, z-index

I have beat my head on this for over an hour and I need your help, I am creating a web form and I am having the most difficult time getting these shadow elements pushed behind the form and not the container. I have tried giving the .form class div a z-index property with no success. It just keeps it in front of the form. Without a z-index propery being established it goes all the way back to the container .mainContent div. Please help! I have added it to codepen for everyones added convenience. Thanks in advance for any and all input.

HTML AND CSS BELOW:

```
    <div class="mainContent">
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <p>
        <label id="yname">Your Name:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="yname" type="text" name="yourname" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label id="subject">Subject:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label id="email">E-mail:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label id="comments">Your comments:</label>
    <br>
    <textarea id="comments" name="comments" maxlength="150" rows="10" cols="40">
    </textarea>
    </p>
    <p id="buttons">
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Send it!">
        <input id="button" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>

.mainContent{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-bottom:45px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    padding-top:25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.mainContent:before, .mainContent:after
{
  content:"";
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:-100;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  box-shadow:0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
  border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 

.mainContent:after
{
  right:10px; 
  left:auto;
  -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
  -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
  -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
  -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
  transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}

.form{
    background-color:grey;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius:2px;
    position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.fieldset{  
    border:none;
    }

fieldset p{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%;
    max-width:300px;
    padding:15px;
    }

label#yname, label#subject, label#email{
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:1.0em;
    color:black;
    width:300px;
    height:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

input#yname, input#subject, input#email{
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:350px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

label#comments{
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:300px;
    height:25px;
    color:#000;
    float:left;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:1.0em;
}

textarea#comments{
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:350px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border-radius:3px;
}

p#buttons{
    margin:0 auto;  
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    display:block;
}

#button{
    width:100px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-family: 'hotpapis';
    font-size:1.25em;
    margin:10px;
    border-radius:3px;
    height:50px;
    }

/* ============================
   ==== Form Shadow Effect ====
   ============================ */

.form:before, .form:after{
    z-index: -1; 
    position: absolute; 
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 45%; 
    height:25px;
    max-width:600px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
} 
.form:after{
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
}
```

URL:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBQGjZ

Comment: didnt get you..waht is that you actually want?

Comment: So you trying to get those shadows behind the gray box?

Comment: I want to get those shadow boxes behind the grey box, yes. Currently when I force it back. It goes behind the container div. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest solution:

```
form {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 grey;
}
```

make the form grey not the .form

Comment: So essentially, I was styling the incorrect element! I was styling the ".form" class instead of the form itself! Thank-you so much for your help! Also, to keep it shorter, by using:      form {
    background:grey;
} and it worked as well! Updated the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYVdYb